# Delayed::Job.enqueue queuing up jobs, and Heroku clearing them from the queue, but my perform method is never called; why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job

I am enqueuing jobs in my Rakefile's cron task, as such:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(MyJob.new(variable))
```

I have a class in /lib as follows:

```
class MyJob < Struct.new(:variable)
    def perform
        Watchdog.create(:module => 'MyJob', :messagetype => 'Notice', :message => "Variable is #{variable}")
    end
end
```

I have a Watchdog class, as follows:

```
class Watchdog < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :id,
            :module,
            :message_type,
            :message,
            :created_at,
            :updated_at
end
```

I have deployed this to Heroku.  After I run heroku rake cron, I see a job gets placed in my Delayed_jobs table (e.g., it is enqueued), and I see that after I add a worker, it is removed from the queue.  However a call to Watchdog.all returns an empty set.

Therefore, it appears that the job is enqueued and dequeued, but that the perform method of my MyJob object is not executed.

I am running Rails 3 and Ruby 1.8.7 on Heroku.

Does anyone know why my perform method isn't being called?  Thanks very much for your help.  I'm relatively new to Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I write my DelayedJob classes would be in this format:

```
class MyJob
    attr_accessor :variable

    def initialize(variable)
       self.variable = variable 
    end

    def perform
        Watchdog.create(:module => 'MyJob', :messagetype => 'Notice', :message => "Variable is #{variable}")
    end  
end
```

This may be functionally equivalent to what you are doing, but I know this form works.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, with very much respect to both of those who offered possible solutions to this problem, neither was on the mark.  Upon much further investigation, what I determined is that my MyJob class was not available to the job:work rake task when it ran on Heroku (or on my local machine for that matter).  What I did to solve this was to include in my config/application.rb file the line:

```
require './lib/my_job.rb'
```

Then, when Delayed::Job dequeued the job and YAML::load()ed the handler, the class definition was available to it, it was able to create the new object and run the perform method on it.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that it's not delayed job at all. Maybe the code itself is failing, not the job enqueue/dequeue. Try checking `heroku logs` and see if it's failing for some reason.

Also, are you positive that MyJob.perform works as expected? You can use `heroku console` to start an interactive ruby shell directly on Heroku. Try initializing a `MyJob` class and running `perform` to make sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

## Possibility 1

Class `Watchdog` has attribute `message_type`, but your job creates a `Watchdog` with an attribute `messagetype`.

## Possibility 2

DelayedJob may not be able to serialize and deserialize a job class inheriting from `Struct.new(:variable)`.

Try the approach that Steve Wilhelm suggested and just use a "normal" class definition:

```
class MyJob
  attr_accessor :variable

  initialize(variable)
    self.variable = variable
  end

  def perform
    Watchdog.create(
      :module => 'MyJob',
      :message_type => 'Notice',
      :message => "Variable is #{variable}"
    )
  end  
end
```